# Persmision denied in a fresh installed python google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, linux-mint

I am trying to run my server on a Linux mint 18.1 machine on a google app engine.
The following command :

```
/home/mint/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --log_level info --storage_path /media/mint/TI31315100A/PycharmProjects/database.db /media/mint/TI31315100A/PycharmProjects/optimallinux
```

Returns the following error :

```
bash: /home/mint/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py: Permission denied
```

I have checked the pathes and the files, everything is right.
Also, I have tried to run the command with sudo and reinstalled the app-engine sevral times, but nothing helped.

Comment: Did you try: `python /home/mint/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --log_level info --storage_path /media/mint/TI31315100A/PycharmProjects/database.db /media/mint/TI31315100A/PycharmProjects/optimallinux
` ?